# get the rendering of an html js in a controller (symfony2) before any action has been done

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, file-get-contents

Could you please help me with this issue?

I have a js file that is connected to an API... it can get information about geolocalisation.

Anyway, I need to get this information in a **symfony2** controller, but before any rendering (before the first rendering), any clues please?

**PS :** i could try `file_get_contents`, but this works with remote links, but not with a local file (where i put the html js). There is something I don't understant.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Call the api directly from php, via curl or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can follow this scenario :

- A first action of your controller calls a page where js is and colls the api
- This page then calls a second action of your controller (via window.location.href for example) and sends it the information, so the action can render what you want

Comment: Thank you Xavier,

I did this (actually, i used a "fake" controller) but I thought it might be a more "elegant" and especially "performing" solution. May be not! Thank you a lot anyway!!